latexdiff preamble scope and control over includegraphics and verbatim differences styles

Cross-posting from this GitHub issue.

latexdiff offers a few options for defining styles, in addition to defining a preamble file with the --preamble option. It seems however, that the preamble file only replaces a small subset of the commands that are generated by latex diff, and leaves the user with no control over the styles for includegraphics (e.g., \DIFaddincludegraphics) for figures and DIFcode (e.g., \lstdefinelanguage{DIFcode}) for listings/verbatim environments.
I would like graphics and listings to use the same colors and underlining as the \DIFadd and \DIFdel commands.
Is there a way to override these settings without manually modifying the generated diff TeX file?

I am afraid there is probably no straightforward way to achieve this currently. It is a reasonable feature request; as you already submitted an issue on the github repository, this is on the list, but I am not able to provide a timescale.
